# Unable to find an accessible element with the role "graphics-document"

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

**Requirement:**
Check whether an icon is present on DOM.

**Test case that I've written:**

```html
render(
    <div>
        <svg height="100" width="100">
            <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" stroke="black" fill="red" />
        </svg>
    </div>
);

expect(screen.getByRole('graphics-document')).toBeInTheDocument();
```

[The list of roles have been defined in [W3 documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#docconformance) as referenced by [Jest documentation](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/byrole/#api).]

**Error:**

Above test case gives the following error:

```bash
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "graphics-document"
```

The SVG icon is getting rendered on DOM but the test case fails. Why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

RTL doesn't support it yet. `@testing-library/dom` provides the queries `getBy*`, `queryBy*`, it depends on `aria-query` package.

`aria-query` package adds `graphics-*` roles in v5.1.0, see [PR](https://github.com/A11yance/aria-query/pull/338) and the code of [graphics-document](https://github.com/A11yance/aria-query/blob/v5.1.0/scripts/roles.json#L2955) role.

`@testing-library/react` v13.4.0(latest version currently) uses `@testing-library/dom` v8.5.0, see [dependency](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/blob/v13.4.0/package.json#LL49C5-L49C28) in `package.json`.

But the `@testing-library/dom` v8.19.0(latest version currently) still use `aria-query` v5.0.0, see [dependency](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/blob/v8.19.0/package.json#L65) in the `package.json` file.